# Passing the contents of the selected row to another activity

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, textview, custom-adapter

Can anyone advise me on how to pass the values of the selected row in a custom viewList to another activity in android. What i mean is that i have a custom ListView which has 2 textView and a checkbox. When the user checks a checkbox and hits the submit button i want to store the values of the 2 textView fields and pass it along to the next activity. Passing to the activity is not the problem. The problem is i cant figure out how to store the values of the checked row.
The code is pasted below.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class contacts extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    static final String TAG = "contacts";
    ArrayList<String> contactName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> contactNumber = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> checkboxArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
    Button AddNumber;
    String numberIntent;
    View vi;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lists);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        // adding
        AddNumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddNumbers);
        AddNumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuilder checkedContacts = new StringBuilder();
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick" + myAdapter.mCheckStates.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < contactName.size(); i++)

                {
                    if (myAdapter.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                        checkedContacts.append(contactName.get(i).toString());
                        checkedContacts.append("\n");

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No OnClick" + contactName.get(i).toString());
                    }

                }

                Toast.makeText(contacts.this, checkedContacts,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        myAdapter.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String name = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Log.d(TAG, "getAllContacts" + phoneNumber);
            contactName.add(name);
            contactNumber.add(phoneNumber);

        }

        cursor.close();
        Intent in = new Intent(this, TrackLogic.class);
        in.putExtra("contact", contactName.toArray());

        in.putExtra("contact1", contactNumber.toArray());
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView phoneView, contactView;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        MyAdapter() {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(contactName.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) contacts.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return contactName.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            contactView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);
            phoneView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_id);
            contactView.setText(contactName.get(position));
            phoneView.setText(contactNumber.get(position));
            checkBox.setTag(position);
            checkBox.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


            return vi;
        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {

            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
            Log.d(TAG, "setChecked");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use shared prefs (probably a good idea) - something along these lines might be what you are looking for:

```
//in caller activity (save shared prefs value) ...
String phone = phoneView.getText().toString();

private SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences("yourPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("phone", phone);  
editor.commit();


//in called activity ...
private SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs = getSharedPreferences("yourPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String phone=prefs.getString("phone", null);    //will be null if "phone" not found
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: can you show me how can i implement this on my code? a snippet would be great

Comment: how should i pass the prefs between two activities? Can i use intents?

Comment: My code is fairly complete - you don't pass the prefs, the prefs pass the data. Just implement "as is" and take it from there.

Comment: So you are saying that i dont need intent to move from one screen to other? The prefs do that for me?

Comment: Ohh nevermind i just realized what a dumb question i asked..THANKS

Comment: Hey there is one thing weird here.. The prefs displays the right data on the toast but doesnt do the same thing on the logcat..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different options that Android provides for storing persistent data.  They are documented in the following link:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

You may want to start with a basic SharedPreferences implementation and go from there.

Comment: I was hoping there could be some way i could retrieve the values of the checked row using some methods available to checkBox. I am not sure though how to go about it

Comment: How long are you looking to store the data for?

Comment: Well the data that is passed will be used kind of default values by the next activity for further operations.

Comment: So, you're not actually storing the data in a persistent manor.  You just need to know how to pass the value of the checkbox specifically?  Basically, if the checkbox is checked or not?

Comment: No i can check if the checkbox is checked or not... All i want is to be able to display the record of the column selected in the next activity